# Big "O" Notation

Tags: asymptotics

Prove the following statements are false:

1. $e^x-1=\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$
2. $x^{-2}=\mathcal{O}(\cot x)$ as $x\to 0$

For the first one, I tried to graph them and to me it seems like $e^x-1$ blows up eventually. But I don't know how to prove it formally.

And for the second one, I have no idea. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: $e^x-1$ blows up as $x\to \infty$ but your problem says $x\to 0.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so when $x\to0$, $e^x-1\to0$ and $x^2\to0$, then how should I disprove that statement?

Answer (score 2):

Question 1.
Using Taylor series for $e^x$
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}...$$
We have as x approach 0

$$e^x -1 = x + \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}...$$

$$e^x -1 = x + O(x^2) \neq O(x^2)$$

Question 2.
Using Taylor series for $cot(x)$
$$cot(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{3}  - \frac{x^3 }{45} - ...$$
Taking the Big O notation

$$O(cot(x)) = O(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{3}  - \frac{x^3 }{45} - ...)$$

$$O(cot(x)) = O(\frac{1}{x})$$
However

$$x^{-2} = O(x^{-2}) \neq  O(\frac{1}{x})$$

$$x^{-2}  \neq  O(cot(x))$$
Look up Taylor series from Wolfram Alpha

Comment: that might be a stupid question.. but how do you define $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ and $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: @fcc Do you have the definition of what it means for something to be of order $O(f(x))$?

Comment: @AnyAD I know that $x_n=O(a_n)$ means $|x_n|\leq C|a_n|$. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: So it seems that you know the definition for sequenced. Equivalent definition exists for functions. So $g(x)$ is of order  $f (x)$ at some point (or as x approaches some point, or plus/minus infinity, if there is a positive constant $M$ st $|g (x)|\leq M|f (x)|$ as $x$ ...

Comment: @fcc So given $g (x)$ you could attempt finding such $f$ and $M$. Or if given a candidate  $f$, you can attempt to disprive that it satisfies the requirement, as you seem to have been asked to do. You have both $f,g$ and need to show that there is no $M$ for which the condition will hold.